# How to construct a loop for with 2 or more variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, combinations

I'm new using this solution. I hope that my doubt can help other people as well.

I'm trying to use the "for" loop on RSTUDIO with 2 variables (years and quarters) in due to save every combination of years and quarters in a data.frame, which is named using the combination of these 2 variables as well.

For example:

```
years = 2012, 2013, ... , 2022
quarters = 1, ... , 4

data_2012_1 <- get_pnadc(year = 2012, quarter = 1, design = FALSE) 
# this step is actually a command of the IBGE's PNADC package
# that is from where I'm trying to get the data.frames
```

This is the exact point where I paste my trying-to-code:

```
years <- 2012:2021
quarters <- 1:4
union <- expand.grid(years,quarters)
union <- paste(union$Var1,union$Var2,sep = "_")
union
```

(until here, I can see all the possible matches that I was spectating for, but in the next step, the things get worse).

```
for (i in union) {
  data_*no idea* <- get_pnadc(year = *no idea2*, quarter = *no idea 3*, design = FALSE)
}
```

I don't even have an output because I know that my code will not work, but getting all the combinations in separated data.frames is what I want to get.

I would feel very gratefully if someone could help me with this.

Comment: My first question would be: are you sure that you need to separate the combinations into individual data frames? Depending on what you want to do next with the data it is often unnecessary and indeed easier to work with one data frame.

Comment: Hi, neilfws. Thanks for your commentary. Indeed, I think that your question makes sense, but I must say that not every variable continues year-by-year, so I think that this is a game-changing, unfortunately. I need to rename some variables before clustering all data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a nested forloop

```
years <- 2012:2021
quarters <- 1:4

final_data <- list()

for(i in years){
   for(j in quarters){
     nm <- paste('data',i, j, sep='_')
     final_data[[nm]] <- get_pnadc(year = i, quarter = j, design = FALSE) 
   }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I asked for. Thanks a lot, onyambu.